# How To Share User Preferences Between Devices With Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, roaming-profile

I've been making Windows apps (C# / XAML), for a while, and there is a built-in `RoamingSettings` space so the app can share preferences across multiple Windows devices (using the same Microsoft Account).  Since Xamarin can work across multiple platforms, is there a way to do this?

I was thinking about some form of internet database, but I'm not hip on storing user data.  Plus, it would either require authentication or store everyone's data in one big table.

I was thinking that [Project Rome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices) would be good for this, but it seems to be more geared towards hand-off workflows (not just sharing a font size or something).

Do you guys have any easy ideas (I stress the word "easy", as I'm just a hobbyist and not a real programmer).

Comment: doing this in cross-platform cross-device way is going to require some sort of remote datastore with user auth

Answer (score 1):

Check out Visual Studio Mobile Center and EasyTables. That should do what you want, but needs an Azure subscription. It's in preview at the moment but works pretty well.

https://mobile.azure.com/